# Rails fixture doesn't recognize a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, ruby-on-rails-6, belongs-to

I have 2 models :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games, dependent: :nullify
```

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :playlist, optional: true
```

In my fixtures, game only belongs_to users. My only fixtures are :

**user.yml**

```
michel:
  id: 1
  pseudo: michelchardou
  email: mich@chardou.com
  encrypted_password: User.digest('password')
  admin: false
```

**game.yml**

```
game1:
  user: michel
  token: 123456
  total_score: 0
```

My basic tests work for

```
  test "should get expected game fixture token" do
    assert_equal '123456', @game1.token
    assert_equal 0, @game1.total_score
  end
```

but the following raises an error :

```
  test "should get expected game fixture user" do
    assert_equal 'michel', @game1.user
  end
```

the error is :

```
Failure:
GameTest#test_should_get_expected_game_fixture_user [/Users/pierre/code/pierregarciafr/wadzatsong/test/models/game_test.rb:25]:
Expected: "michel"
  Actual: nil
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're manually assigning the id your user (michel) is going to have, and you should leave that to Rails (or the ORM), try deleting that line.

The fixture for the user michel should be like:

```
michel:
  pseudo: michelchardou
  email: mich@chardou.com
  encrypted_password: User.digest('password')
  admin: false
```

In the other hand your first example works without problem because you're not testing the relationship between both models, you're checking what was explicitly added to the fixture file.

Comment: Thanx! I went forward one step thanx to you. I cancelled the id, and now he recognizes the @game1.user as an object. I get a different error message : ```Failure:
GameTest#test_should_get_expected_game_fixture_user [/Users/pierre/code/pierregarciafr/wadzatsong/test/models/game_test.rb:25]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"michel"
+#<User id: 575920385, email: "mich@chardou.com", created_at: "2020-06-23 12:29:43", updated_at: "2020-06-23 12:29:43", pseudo: "michelchardou", admin: false>``` Is this format discrepancy normal ?

Comment: Sure, that's the expected behavior @pierrecode, because you're testing @game1.user must be equal to the string "michel", but Rails will always return the object related in that case, so it's going to give you the "whole" user. What you can do is to update the test to check for the `@game1.user.name`.

Comment: ```# Running:

..............```thank u so much @SebastianPalma , u made my fixture day :)

Comment: tought I 'd already  accepted. I clicked each of your answers. I'm a newby here, tell me anything else I can do ?

Comment: got it ! looool